Were there books published in 1960s to late 1970s that reflected the effect of the Cold War on historians' views of the Space Race?
Were there books published in 1960s to late 1970s that reflected the effect of the Cold War on historians' views of the Space Race of the 1960s?

Can the answer be anything but Yes?

Welcome to Stack Exchange @user54978! Just to let you know, while this question is certainly on-topic here, it might receive better answers about how spaceflight histories published in the '60s and '70s were written and what slant they may have taken in History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange. If you'd like your question migrated there, you can always click "flag" and ask for "moderator assistance".

@StevePemberton maybe I've been Rorschached here "...books...that reflected the effect...on historians' views..."  You're right, it's not asking for about historians, it's asking for books that show the effect of the Cold War on the author's view on what they chronicled.
